# Can I write ~€100 to denote an approximate amount of 100 euros?

Tags: style-manuals, symbols, money

I am currently using the expression “~€100” to symbolically denote an approximate amount of one hundred euros. However, I’m not sure whether the symbol ~ followed by the symbol € and the amount of money is the correct way to go. Any help?

Comment: Who is the intended readership? Will they recognise the symbols?

Comment: It would be clearer (to me) as either "~100 euros" or as "about €100".

Comment: It is for a CV.

Comment: Because 100 is a "round number", it's often assumed to mean ***about*** 100 rather than ***exactly*** 100. So I suggest not bothering to explicitly include a potentially unfamiliar symbol OR the word "about". On a CV it probably doesn't actually matter whether the person reading it assumes ***exactly*** or not, but he probably wouldn't anyway.

Comment: Well, the one hundred was just an easy example. The quantities are rounded (all of them end either in 0 or 5). Should I round them more at the expense of precision?

Comment: The two adjacent symbols look odd. If you say "about €100" readers will barely notice the "about". But once you start rounding to €5 that's looking like an exact amount. It's strange though, why you should be reeling off a succession of figures in a CV. You could perhaps mention figures once, "the activities were for sums of €100 or less."

Comment: I’m trying to keep the entire expression as short as possible for reasons of space. What about moving the € symbol to the end (i.e., ~100€)?

Comment: You could use "c. €100" if you're desperate to get a short form; it's probably considered more formal as an abbreviation for circa/about than your squiggle. (But omitting it is even shorter.)

Comment: Why would a monetary amount be on a CV in the first place? You could just spell it all out: "about a hundred euros"

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I never thought about the “c.” option: should I write in small letters even if it’s the first letter of the syntagma? Also, the reason to include a monetary amount in a CV is to specifically quantify grants obtain throughout the years.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not so much about the use of the English language as it is about the use of international symbols, and for a very specific context (a CV).

Comment: Fine with the closure as I got enough input from other users, but if this is not the forum to ask these questions, I don’t which one is…